# Paypal invalid token error when creating a recurring payment profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, express-checkout, paypal

I am trying to setup a recurring payment profile via the ExpressCheckout API of Paypal in Ruby on Rails with the help of [paypal-express gem](https://github.com/nov/paypal-express/wiki/Recurring-Payment) but i keep getting error code 11502 (Invalid token) => [Paypal error code documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/#id09C3G0B0JK3)

The documentation is a bit unclear because there it is not saying what's missing:

> One or more subscription detail fields are missing from the request.

I have checked the required field in the documentation [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) but i don't think i missed any. No need for shipping details as we don't ship a product. 
Here is a log of what is being sent to Paypal when i am doing the checkout and then creating the recurring profile:

> SetExpressCheckout
>
> Parameters:
>
> {:RETURNURL=>"http://localhost:3000/paypal/validate",
>   :CANCELURL=>"http://localhost:3000/paypal/cancel",
>   :REQCONFIRMSHIPPING=>0, :NOSHIPPING=>1, :ALLOWNOTE=>0,
>   :PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=>"88.00", :PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=>"0.00",
>   :PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=>"0.00",
>   :PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=>"HKD", :PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=>"Plus x
>   2-month subscription x 2 staff", :LOCALECODE=>:fr}
>
> Response:
>
> > TOKEN=EC%2d0H440138VJ9552235&TIMESTAMP=2015%2d04%2d25T08%3a38%3a42Z&CORRELATIONID>=48742557da98&ACK=Success&VERSION=88%2e0&BUILD=16428450
>
> CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
>
> Parameters:
>
> {:TOKEN=>"EC-0H440138VJ9552235", :BILLINGPERIOD=>:Month,
>   :BILLINGFREQUENCY=>2, :TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=>0, :AMT=>"88.00",
>   :CURRENCYCODE=>"HKD", :SHIPPINGAMT=>"0.00", :TAXAMT=>"0.00", 
>   :DESC=>"Plus x 2-month subscription x 2 staff", :MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=>0,
>   :PROFILESTARTDATE=>"2015-04-25 16:39:24"}
>
> Response:
>
> > TIMESTAMP=2015%2d04%2d25T08%3a39%3a26Z&CORRELATIONID=533964ff183a1&ACK=Failure&VE>RSION=88%2e0&BUILD=16398710&L_ERRORCODE0=11502&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Invalid%20Token&L_>LONGMESSAGE0=The
> >     %20token%20is%20invalid&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

Do you guys have any ideas of what could be wrong? I can execute a payment without any issue, the issue appear when creating a recurring profile.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind! 
I found what was wrong misread the gem wiki (https://github.com/nov/paypal-express/wiki/Recurring-Payment) and mistakenly mix instant payment request with recurring profile creation so there was no billing_agreement_description nor billing_agreements in the data sent to paypal...